# Jquery dynamic options hide/show in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have following simple Html code with SELECT with the same class forms with identical options values

```
<select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>

<select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>
```

I just want to do click on a dropdown dynamic show and hide value from ALL SELECT with one class.

```
jQuery.each($("select.gr-fields-select"), function(){            
$(".gr-fields-select").change(function() {
if($(".gr-fields-select").val() != "") {
$(".gr-fields-select option[value!="+$(".gr-fields-select").val()+"]").show();
$(".gr-fields-select option[value="+$(".gr-fields-select").val()+"]").hide();
} else {
$(".gr-fields-select option[value!="+$(".gr-fields-select").val()+"]").show();
}
});
})
```

Please check the jdfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mhassan94/d6j3fpt2/3/

If a select one dropdown value, they hide from All dropdown but if a change select dropdown value they show previous value and hide the new value in All dropdown.

How is that better to achieve?

Comment: wouldn't a multiselect be much easier and accomplish what you want? select2 has nice ones https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```js
$(".gr-fields-select").change(function(){
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $(".gr-fields-select").each(function(ind, item){
     if($(item).find(':selected').value!=selectedValue){
     $(item).find('option').each(function(index,option){
        if(option.value!=selectedValue){
          $(option).show();
        }else{
          $(option).hide();
        }
      });
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>First</label><select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>

<br>
<label>Second</label><select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>

<br>
```

If you need to hide the value selected in one particular select element,from all the values populated in rest of the select elements try this,

```js
$(".gr-fields-select").change(function(){
 
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  var previousValue = $(this).data("new");
  if(previousValue!=undefined){
   $(this).data("old",previousValue);
  }
  $(this).data("new",selectedValue);
  $(".gr-fields-select").each(function(ind, item){
     if($(item).find(':selected').value!=selectedValue){
     $(item).find('option').each(function(index,option){
        if(option.value==selectedValue){
           $(option).hide();
        }
        if(option.value==previousValue){
           $(option).show();
        }
      });
    }  
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>


<select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>

<select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks No I don't want to remove the values from dropdown.
If a select one dropdown value, they hide from All dropdown but if a change select dropdown value they show previous value and hide the new value in All dropdown.

Comment: @MHassan I have updated the answer. Please check again.

Comment: Great.could you please mark it as answer if it's helps.

Comment: yes sure. one more thing I ask if they are three select box how they should hide two values from a single dropdown?

Comment: I didn't get what you have asked correctly but as I understood, the answer that I have provided before the edit was handling that particular situation. you can give a distinct id to the third select box, and pass the selected value for the above function as a parameter to hide that option.

Comment: I said it's working on two select box right now. If they are three select box what do I should? Now I want to hide two values from the dropdown (first value and the second value of dropdown)
Code:https://jsfiddle.net/mhassan94/tzwbvpgL/2/

Comment: [@Thilanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423695/thilanka-deshan-minion91) any suggestion ?

Comment: so ideally you want to hide the selected value of a particular dropdown from the values populated in rest of all other dropdowns?

Comment: yes you are right. can you please tell me the code what should i change in my code [@Thilanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423695/thilanka-deshan-minion91)

Comment: I am not good in jquery can plz help me? [@Thilanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423695/thilanka-deshan-minion91)
Code: jsfiddle.net/mhassan94/tzwbvpgL/2

Comment: i am waiting for your response [@Thilanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423695/thilanka-deshan-minion91)

Comment: @MHassan is that what you want to do?

Comment: [@Thilanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423695/thilankad) i need you help again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517986/jquery-hide-select-value-dropdown
can you solve this issue plz? [@Thilanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423695/thilankad)

Answer (score 0):

So in the don't re-invent the wheel category. I'm thinking a multi select such as select2 might accomplish what you want alot easier than the multiple drop downs. select 2 even lets you limit your selection length if you only want two.  I think with multiple drop downs there is alot to track. especially if you want more than two drop downs. What if  they choose the selects out of order?  run the snippet below to see a possible implementation using a multiselect

```js
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#multipleSelectExample").select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 2,
          closeOnSelect: false,
          allowClear: true
        });
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css">

<select id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select" multiple>
<option value="1042000018355">Product Management</option>
<option value="1042000018356">QA</option>
<option value="1042000018357">Sales</option>
</select>
```